# How to sort a object by first element come

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to sort an object by first Component came, not sort by identifier.

I mapped a object JSON and tried to use `shift()`, `push()`, `forEach()` but always return the object sort by identider.
For my code:

```
listDices = [
{value: 1, hidden: false, id:0},
{value: 2, hidden: false, id:1},
{value: 6, hidden: false, id:2},
{value: 6, hidden: false, id:3},
{value: 5, hidden: false, id:4},
];

const arrMiniDices = [];
        listDices.map(item => {
            if (item.hidden) {
                arrMiniDices.push(
                        <BtnDice 
                            key={item.id}
                            value={item.value}
                            className="btn__dice--small"
                            onClick={() => this.handleHideDice(item.id)}
                        />
                )
            }
        });
```

I put arrMiniDices in a Component:

```
<ViewSectionToolsResult
      arrMiniDices={arrMiniDices}
/>
```

For example i have a Array:

```
const arr = [
{id0: "a"},
{id1: "b"},
{id2: "c"},
{id3: "d"},
{id4: "e"}
];
```

all items have onclick,
when i click on "d", "b", "c", "a", "e" i want arrMiniDices =

```
[{id3: "d"},
{id1: "b"},
{id2: "c"},
{id0: "a"},
{id4: "e"}];
```

just by order of click
But i have always

```
[{id0: "a"},
{id1: "b"},
{id2: "c"},
{id3: "d"}
{id4: "e"}];
```

Comment: could you please be more specific about what you want as the result .... i mean could you post an example of the output you are expecting

Comment: Sorry but it's hard to understand what you want to achieve. What do you call identifier ?

Comment: A clear question shows the sample input (you included), the code you've tried (you included), and _the desired result_ (which is missing).  We're all lost without knowing the desired result.

Comment: Are you sure the actual resulting array is being sorted by itself? Where are you inspecting the output to determine that? Most browser dev tools will automatically sort arrays/objects when you "preview" them, so check the raw output first to confirm.

Comment: Since you are iterating over `listDices`, you will always get items in that order. You need to maintain another array, like `diceOrder`, to store the order in which the dice are clicked and iterate over that array.

Comment: So basically ure asking for the logic for handleHideDice?

Comment: it looks like I have to use another array for the order of click, i will try later, my brain explode. 
I push one by one the components so I do not understand why I have to change the order, since the push method adds at the end of the array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can keep another array to store the `id` the order in which dice are clicked. And use that array to load components.

Something similar to this:

```
const listDices = [
{value: 1, hidden: false, id:0},
{value: 2, hidden: false, id:1},
{value: 6, hidden: false, id:2},
{value: 6, hidden: false, id:3},
{value: 5, hidden: false, id:4},
];

const diceOrder = [];

handleDiceClick(diceId) {
  // ... Your stuff
  ...
  // update the dice order array
  // You need other logic to update the array. I am showing only adding.
  diceOrder.push(diceId);
}

const arrMiniDices = [];
diceOrder.map(id => {
  const item = listDices.find(dice => dice.id === id);
  if (item.hidden) {
    arrMiniDices.push(
      <BtnDice 
        key={item.id}
        value={item.value}
        className="btn__dice--small"
        onClick={() => handleHideDice(item.id)}
      />
    );       
  }
});
```

You have to use `handleDiceClick` somewhere.

Comment: since the good methode, try later, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could simply try to reverse the order that's all

suppose this is the final array

```
console.log(result)
//[{id2: "c"},{id1: "b"}];

console.log(result.reverse())

//[{id1: "b"},{id2: "c"}];
```

array.push will pop the lastin as first out by default

Comment: yes thank, i will re-edit, i'm not explicit enough

Comment: great..read more about FIFO to have an idea.(Y). Reversing result will solve your current issue